# "file not found" Error in objective c to swift bridging header

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, objective-c-swift-bridge

I have placed the `.framework` at the target level (outside the swift project folder). I gave the `#import` path in bridging file as `(framework)/.h(file)` which seems correct, but I have the same error. I've already tried all possibilities. I may be      missing out on something.

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: can you add that framework using cocoapods, you can create a bridging header by creating a new objective C File and it will automatically pop up for bridging header then you can add that framework in your bridging header file.

Comment: I have added the bridging header,that's the reason its giving me the error.Is it because i havent provided any header search path?

Comment: so now it is working fine

Comment: do i need to provide header search path? I'm an absolute noob/newbie in swift so bear with me

Comment: if you are adding framework with cocoapods then you will have to provide the header search path, so best is to use the cocoapods

Comment: ok thanks.I have no idea about cocoapods:(